# Why is PostgreSQL reporting a higher shared_buffers value than the parameter in the configuaration file when trying to enable huge_pages?

Tags: postgresql, shared-buffers

On a 7.5 GB host (Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS), I have allocated 3 GB to `shared_buffers`:

```
postgres=# SHOW shared_buffers;
shared_buffers 
----------------
 3GB
(1 row)
```

with:

```
postgres@my-host:~$ cat /etc/postgresql/10/main/postgresql.conf | grep shared_buffers
shared_buffers = 3072MB         # min 128kB, valid units are kB, MB, GB, TB
```

I have also configured my host with HP as:

```
postgres@my-host:~$ cat /proc/meminfo | grep ^Huge
HugePages_Total:    1600
HugePages_Free:     1600
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
```

With a `Hugepagesize` at 2048 kB, that works out as `1600*2048/1024 = 3200 MB` of HP. When I then try to turn:

```
postgres@raeflightcachemaster0-nonprod:~$ cat /etc/postgresql/10/main/postgresql.conf | grep huge_pages
huge_pages = on
```

PostgreSQL (10.5) is reporting:

```
2018-09-27 09:31:54.397 BST [16739] FATAL:  could not map anonymous shared memory: Cannot allocate memory
2018-09-27 09:31:54.397 BST [16739] HINT:  This error usually means that PostgreSQL's request for a shared memory segment exceeded available memory, swap space, or huge pages. To reduce the request size (currently 3523592192 bytes), reduce PostgreSQL's shared memory usage, perhaps by reducing shared_buffers or max_connections.
2018-09-27 09:31:54.397 BST [16739] LOG:  database system is shut down
pg_ctl: could not start server
Examine the log output.
```

and the DB server fails to start.

My question is, where is it getting the number `3523592192 bytes` from? This value does not match the `shared_buffers = 3072MB` setting in `postgresql.conf` as it works out as `3523592192/1024/1024 = 3360.359375 MB`. I get around the problem by increasing `HugePages_Total` slightly to 1700 so that we have 3400 MB of HP but I don't understand the discrepancy between the reported value of `shared_bufferes` and the configured value. Is this a units issue?

Comment: Did you notice the " perhaps by reducing shared_buffers or max_connections" ?

Comment: What do you have as work_mem and max_connections. Does the product of the two approach 300Mb ?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille, I was focusing on `shared_buffers` and missed `max_connections` but `max_connections` `*` `work_mem` `>> 300 MB` at `16400 MB`.

Comment: What on earth are your values for those parameters?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille, `max_connections = 4100` and `work_mem = 4MB`. Does this have an impact on the value reported in the error message?

Comment: Please tell me, what will be using 4100 simultaneous connections??

Comment: @GerardH.Pille, the devs just handed a test box back and apparently were looking for ways to break it. Going back to the original questions, does `work_mem` get added to the total reported back by the error message?

Comment: I'm not sure, but when I was looking for an answer to your question, someone wrote "work_mem*max_connections*2".  Tell your devs they succeeded in breaking it and to crawl back under their stones.  4100 proves they are ignorant about persistent connections, bad at designing a database and writing good SQL.

Comment: `work_mem` is irrelevant here.  It is allocated in backend-private memory, not shared memory.  It is `max_locks_per_transaction` and few others that are allocated in shared memory scaled for `max_connections`.

Comment: @jjanes, could you point me to some refs or docs where I can look up the full list of the parameters that get included in the `shared_buffers` total and the scaling factor used with `max_connections`? I want to do the calcs to see how it all adds up.

Comment: @dw8547 I'm not aware of any place that pulls this all together.  The exact sizes are going to change from OS/hardware platform to platform, as well as from PostgreSQL version to version.  There are ~31 functions named ending in "ShmemSize" located in src/backend/storage/ipc/ipci.c which would be the place to look.

Comment: @dw8547 did you end up figuring out the discrepancy?

Comment: @Hristo no, I got as far as getting the source code and checking `ipci.c` but I don't know C so didn't get any further.